# The linker is not linking the C and asm object files

Tags: c, assembly, makefile, ld, osdev

I'm working on an OS and I'm trying to get it to load. I have a dummy kernel for now, and I'm trying to get my bootloader to load it im using a make file to do it faster and it keeps giving the same error

```
nasm kernel-entry.asm -f elf -o kernel-entry.o
kernel-entry.asm:4: warning: label alone on a line without a colon might be in error [-w+label-orphan]
ld -m elf_i386 -o zenKernel.bin  kernel-entry.o kernel.o --oformat binary -nostdlib -e _star
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _star; defaulting to 08049000
ld: kernel.o: in function `main':
kernel.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_'
make: *** [Makefile:5: zenKernel.bin] Error 1
```

here is my makefile

```
all: run


zenKernel.bin: kernel-entry.o kernel.o
        ld -m elf_i386 -o $@  $^ --oformat binary -nostdlib -e _star

kernel-entry.o: kernel-entry.asm
        nasm $< -f elf -o $@

kernel.o: kernel.c
        gcc -m32 -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@ -nostdlib

boot.bin: boot.asm
        nasm $< -f bin -o $@

zenOS.bin: boot.bin zenKernel.bin
        cat $^ > $@

run: zenOS.bin
        qemu-system-i386 -fda $<

clean:
        $(RM) *.bin *.o *.dis
```

here is the kernel.c

```c
void main() {
  char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
  *video_memory = 'x';
}
```

here is the kernel-entry.asm

```
[bits 32]

section .text
globle_star
extern main

_star:
  call main
  jmp $
```

I've tried all the things that I can think of.

Comment: Like the NASM warning warned you, `globle_star` is getting treated as a label `globle_star:` because it's not recognized as a directive.  You want `global _star`, using the `global` directive to export the symbol-name `_star`.